# Custom endpoint and X-WP-TotalPages (headers)

Tags: headers, wp-api

I have a custom endpoint defined like so:

```
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'menc/v1', '/crosscat/(?P<dept>[\w-]+)/(?P<cat>[\w-]+)', array(
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'dept_cat_api',
            'args' => array(
                'dept' => array(
                    'sanitize_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                        return sanitize_text_field( $param );
                    }
                ),
                'cat' => array(
                    'sanitize_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                        return sanitize_text_field( $param );
                    }
                ),
                'per_page' => array(
                    'default' => 10,
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
                ),
                'page' => array(
                    'default' => 1,
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
                ),
                'orderby' => array(
                    'default' => 'date',
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
                ),
                'order' => array(
                    'default' => 'desc',
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
                ),
            ),
        ) );
    } );

    function dept_cat_api( $request ) {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'crosspost',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( $request['dept'] ),
                ),
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category',
                    'field'    => 'slug',
                    'terms'    => array( $request['cat'] ),
                ),
            ),
            'per_page' => $request['per_page'],
            'page' => $request['page'],
            'orderby' => $request['orderby'],
            'order' => $request['order']
        );

        $posts = get_posts( $args );

        if ( empty( $posts ) ) return new WP_Error( 'no_posts', 'Invalid term(s)', array( 'status' => 404 ) );

        $controller = new WP_REST_Posts_Controller('post');

        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $response = $controller->prepare_item_for_response( $post, $request );
            $data[] = $controller->prepare_response_for_collection( $response );  
        }

// return results
        return new WP_REST_Response($data, 200);

    }
```

Remotely I'm having a problem. When I call the route everything seems fine with the content, however both `X-WP-TotalPages` and `X-WP-Total` return empty responses.

```
    object(Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary)#991 (1) {
      ["data":protected]=>
      array(20) {
        ["server"]=>
        string(5) "nginx"
        ["date"]=>
        string(29) "Wed, 14 Jun 2017 14:07:51 GMT"
        ["content-type"]=>
        string(31) "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ["content-length"]=>
        string(6) "104787"
        ["expires"]=>
        string(29) "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"
        ["pragma"]=>
        string(8) "no-cache"
        ["x-robots-tag"]=>
        string(7) "noindex"
        ["link"]=>
        string(65) "; rel="https://api.w.org/""
        ["x-content-type-options"]=>
        string(7) "nosniff"
        ["access-control-expose-headers"]=>
        string(27) "X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages"
        ["access-control-allow-headers"]=>
        string(27) "Authorization, Content-Type"
        ["allow"]=>
        string(3) "GET"
        ["x-cacheable"]=>
        string(5) "SHORT"
        ["vary"]=>
        string(22) "Accept-Encoding,Cookie"
        ["cache-control"]=>
        string(28) "max-age=600, must-revalidate"
        ["accept-ranges"]=>
        string(5) "bytes"
        ["x-cache"]=>
        string(6) "HIT: 1"
        ["x-pass-why"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["x-cache-group"]=>
        string(6) "normal"
        ["x-type"]=>
        string(7) "default"
      }
    }
```

Ideally I need both populated, but I could make do with one. I assumed WordPress calculated/populated these via the controller. Do I have to populate them manually? Have I done something incorrectly? Am I experiencing a bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had a quick look and here's how the headers are set in the [`WP_REST_Posts_Controller::get_items()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/get_items/) method:

```
$response  = rest_ensure_response( $posts );
// ...
$response->header( 'X-WP-Total', (int) $total_posts );
$response->header( 'X-WP-TotalPages', (int) $max_pages );
// ...
return $response;
```

where:

```
$total_posts = $posts_query->found_posts;
```

and we could use as @jshwlkr [suggested](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/98703/jshwlkr):

```
$max_pages = $posts_query->max_num_pages;
```

You could emulate that for your custom endpoint, by using `WP_Query` instead of `get_posts()`.

Thanks to @DenisUyeda for [correcting the typo](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270005/custom-endpoint-and-x-wp-totalpages-headers/270128#comment416579_270128).

Comment: Yep, that's what I needed. Part of the problem was that i was trying to pre-optimize and it was tripping me up trying to figure out where to modify the response, as I was returning it directly instead of assigning it to a variable.

In the end it should look more like this.

 `$total = $query->found_posts;
 $pages = $query->max_num_pages;

  $returned = new WP_REST_Response( $data, 200 );
 $returned->header( 'X-WP-Total', $total );
 $returned->header( 'X-WP-TotalPages', $pages );

 return $returned;`

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you.

Comment: Just as @jshwlkr sort of pointed out, about $posts_query->max_pages, WP_Query had a max_num_pages instead. So it's $posts_query->max_num_pages

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer above, I used this code, It works for me.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array());

$posts = $query->get_posts();

$total_posts = $query->found_posts;
$max_pages = $query->max_num_pages;
$returned =  new WP_REST_Response($posts, 200);
$returned->header( 'X-WP-Total', $total_posts );
$returned->header( 'X-WP-TotalPages', $max_pages );
return $returned;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = $query->get_posts();

$total_posts = $query->found_posts;
$max_pages = $query->max_num_pages;
$returned =  new WP_REST_Response($posts, 200);
$returned->header( 'X-WP-Total', $total_posts );
$returned->header( 'X-WP-TotalPages', $max_pages );
return $returned;
```

Where should I put it ? In rest-api.php ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/251943)